# Is this system of equations usable in linear regression?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, linear-regression

I have a set of equations that I want to transform so that I may be able use linear regression to predict constant D:

Equation 1:
$$
y = 1 -\left(\frac{6Sh^{2}}{\beta_{n}^{2}\left(\beta_{n}^{2} + Sh^{2} - Sh\right)}\right)e^{ -\frac{\beta_{n}^{2}}{R^{2}}Dt} 
$$
Where βn is the first root of the equation:
$$
\beta_n  cot⁡(\beta_n ) = 1 - Sh
$$

And
$$
Sh = hR/D.
$$
Originally, equation 1 includes a summation for the second term of all βn roots, but numerically the 2nd+ roots can be estimated to be 0, leaving us with this simplified equation.

Known variables = h (constant), R (constant), t (independent variable, time), and y is the given dependent variable on (0,1).

I have experience with transforming linear equations for prediction using linear regression, but I am unsure if it is even possible to do so in this case given the definition of βn relying on the constant D, which is to be estimated via regression.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the formatting didn't work, I have updated the equations now. I am currently thinking of solving for D = Beta and using Beta as the dependent variable for regression, but I'm unsure if it is feasible.

Comment: Could you joint to your question at least one representative example : Numerical values of the known constants and data $D(t)$. No graph please.

Comment: An example of the data (all values known, including D): h = 2, R = 50 D = 200, t is on [0,50] where y = (0.0040,...,0.9957).

Comment: Please provide a set of data (10-20 points) as well as the constants.

Comment: Curious why you care to use linear regression. Why not just use nonlinear regression? Seems you could sort this problem out in your preferred programming language fairly easily

Comment: You will only get a good prediction if your data is linear.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the $n$ data points $(t_i,y_i)$, for a given criteria, there is a unique fitting function
$$y=1-A\, e^{-B\, t}$$ for which the parameters are easily obtained. So, at solution, we have
$$A=\frac{6Sh^{2}}{\beta^{2}\left(\beta^{2} + Sh^{2} - Sh\right)}\qquad \text{and} \qquad B=\frac{\beta^{2}}{R^{2}}D$$
$$B=\frac{\beta^{2}}{R^{2}}D \implies \beta=R \sqrt{\frac B D}$$ So, we just need to solve for $D$ the equation
$$R \sqrt{\frac B D} \cot\Bigg[R \sqrt{\frac B D} \Bigg]=1-\frac {h R}D$$ that is to say
$$D=\frac {B\,R^2}{x^2} \implies \qquad \color{red}{x\cot(x)=1-k x^2}\qquad \text{with} \qquad k=\frac{h}{B\,R}$$

We can approximate the solution of $x$ solving for $x$
$$k=\frac{(3-\pi^2)x+\pi^3 }{3\pi^2(\pi-x)}\implies \color{blue}{x_0=\frac{(3k-1)\pi^3 } {(3k-1)\pi^2+3 }}$$ As an indication about the quality of the approximation
$$\int_0^\pi \Bigg[\frac{1-x \cot (x)}{x^2}-\frac{(3-\pi^2)x+\pi^3 }{3\pi^2(\pi-x)} \Bigg]^2\,dx=0.00218$$

The below table gives values of $x_0$, $x_1$ (the first iterate of Newton method applied to the "red" equation) and the solution for a few values of $k$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
k & x_0 & x_1 & \text{solution} \\
 0.5 & 1.95382 & 2.12250 &  2.08158 \\
 1.0 & 2.72712 & 2.74462 &  2.74371 \\
 1.5 & 2.89056 & 2.89677 &  2.89659 \\
 2.0 & 2.96155 & 2.96470 &  2.96464 \\
 2.5 & 3.00124 & 3.00314 &  3.00311 \\
 3.0 & 3.02660 & 3.02786 &  3.02784
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Admitting small errors on the data, select two points $(t_1,y_1)$ and $(t_2,y_2)$. Then
$$k=\frac{\log \left(\frac{1-y_2}{1-y_1}\right)}{t_1-t_2}=\frac{\beta^2}{R^2}D$$

So, we have two equations
$$\beta=R \sqrt{\frac k D}$$
$$\beta\cot(\beta)=1-\frac {h R}D$$ which lead to
$$\beta=\cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{R (D-h R)}{\sqrt{D k}}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

*Please, tell me if I misunderstood or if I made any mistake in this preliminary answer. This problem is very interesting to me.*

If I properly understand, you have $n$ data points $(t_i,y_i)$, $h$ and $R$ being constants and you need to ajust the value of parameter $D$.

The problem does not look simple at all because of the $\beta$ paameter which is an implicit function of $D$.

I suppose that you will agree that the problem is simple if $\beta$ is known. What I would suggest is the following : give $D$ a guessed value $D_0$ which which you compute $\beta_0$; from this $\beta_0$, compute $D_1$ and repeat until convergence of $D$ computed by linear or nonlinear regression.

Assuming $0 \leq \beta \leq \frac \pi 2$, solving the equation $\beta \cot(\beta)=1-Sh$ is not a big problem since
$$\beta \cot(\beta)\sim g(\beta)=\frac{24 \pi ^2+\pi\left(\pi ^4-96 \right) \beta +\left(96-2 \pi ^4\right) \beta
   ^2}{24 \pi ^2+\pi\left(\pi ^4-96  \right) \beta +\left(96+8 \pi ^2-2 \pi ^4\right)
   \beta ^2}\tag 1$$

To give an idea of the quality of the approximation
$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \Big[\beta \cot(\beta)- g(\beta)\Big]^2\, d\beta=9.98\times 10^{-7}$$ whith a maximum absolute error of $0.001342$ around $\beta=1.01857$

which gives, as a very close approximation
$$\beta_0=\frac{48 \pi  Sh}{\left(96-\pi ^4\right) Sh+\pi  \sqrt{\left(\pi ^6-768\right) Sh^2+768 Sh}}$$

To polish the root, I suppose that a single interation of Newton method would be sufficient
$$\beta_1=\beta_0-\frac {\beta_0  \cot (\beta_0 )+Sh-1 } {\cot (\beta_0 )-\beta_0  \csc ^2(\beta_0 ) }$$

Using this $\beta_1$, compute $D_1$ since at this point the model is just
$$y=1- A e^{-B t}$$ easy to linearize. However, I do not recommend you to do so, (except in a preliminary step to get estimates of $(A,B)$) since what is measured is $y_i$ and not $\log(1-y_i$).

Comment: I really like this look at the problem, it is how I was attempting to approach it but my mathematical skills are lacking so I was having trouble reaching this stage. One thing to note is that technically, Sh is not constrained to any upper limit and may have values of Sh ≫ 1, but in reality the value of $\beta$ will be constrained to within the range of $0 \leq \beta \leq \pi$, and I am assuming this changes your initial derivation of $g(\beta)$.

Answer (score 0):

You may handle this problem by working on the unknonw $\beta_n$ rather than $D$. We know that

$$D=\frac{hR}{1-\beta_n  cot⁡(\beta_n )}$$ and $$S_h=1-\beta_n  cot⁡(\beta_n ).$$

So we rewrite

$$y = 1 -\left(\frac{6(1-\beta_n  cot⁡(\beta_n ))^{2}}{\beta_{n}^{2}\left(\beta_{n}^{2} + (1-\beta_n  cot⁡(\beta_n ))^{2} - (1-\beta_n  cot⁡(\beta_n ))\right)}\right)e^{ -\frac{h\beta_{n}^{2}}{R(1-\beta_n  cot⁡(\beta_n ))}t}.$$

Though this expression is a little monstrous and impossible to linearize, it works around the problem of the implicit relation. Now you can set up a least squares minimization problem, which is univariate.

Comment: The least squares minimization  would be a bit funny. Cheers :-)

Comment: This works out quite well for a numerical analysis using a programmatic approach, rather than utilizing the ordinary least squares algorithm.

Comment: @lolwatpie: what do you mean ? As far as I know, there is only one least-square method.